# How does R20D-USB RFID reader read directly into text editors/input forms?

Tags: rfid

I have a R20D-USB RFID reader. When I connect it to the machine, open a text editor application or and webpage with an input form, and read the RFID card the RFID is automatically typed in the text editors/input form. (As I found out to use other RFID readers, we have to develop a script to read the input from the port and insert into our application)

How does R20D-USB RFID reader (uses RS232 port) read directly into text editors/input forms?

I need a technical explanation.

Comment: I don't think this is really on topic for here. But I will guess that the reader shows up as a keyboard not a RS232 device and just "types" the id value read from the card.

Comment: Do you know the right forum to post this question?

Comment: it is unclear if you are asking about the RFID reader or if you are asking about the text editor or the hardware of the computer that the text editor runs on or the operating system that the computer runs  ..... your question is like this one ... `Why is the sky blue? I need a scientific explanation.` .... it would require several volumes of books to explain scientifically

Comment: I explained. Please check

Comment: i think that you have a misconception about the device .... `uses RS232 port` is incorrect  ..... it is most likely `emulates a keyboard` ........ you need to do some research of your own .... start with `what does the device look like to the computer?` ............. `I need a technical explanation.` is still unclear .... your edit did not really add any new information